# Copying Chrome/Firefox bookmarks from Windows to Linux on same computer

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I've had a windows installation on my PC go corrupt. As a result, I can still see all of my data (including everything in `c:/program files`, etc) but I can't actually run any of the programs.

I've got a Linux installation going on the same computer. Can I copy over all of my bookmarks from the old windows installations of Firefox and Chrome into the new Linux installations of these programs? If so, how?

Comment: Just copy of the files to the folder where your bookmarks are stored on your linux operating system.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

**Firefox:**

- Opened the partition which used to be C drive on windows, and went to: Documents and Settings/(user)/Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles
- Open the profile folder in this one, and copy its contents (Ctrl + C)
- Opened Firefox. Clicked Help, Troubleshoot, and then 'Open profile folder'
- Close firefox, and waited for it to terminate completely, before opening the profile folder on Firefox and copying over the contents of profile folder from Windows into this one, replacing all files
- Opened firefox, and voila, all the bookmarks and even extensions are restored.

**Google chrome:**

For Chrome I've only copied the bookmarks, not the rest of the profile, as I didn't want to lose all of my cache/cookies on Linux and have to sign into everything again. It may be possible to copy over the entire profile the same way as for Firefox above, but I haven't tested it.

- Go to Documents and Settings/(user)/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default
- Copy the files 'Bookmarks' and 'Bookmarks.bak' to clipboard
- Go to /home/(user)/.config/google-chrome/Default
- Paste over the Bookmarks / Bookmarks.bak file (This will completely overwrite your Linux's google chrome backups with the ones from Windows)

Done!

**Bonus: FileZilla**

- Go to: Documents and Settings/user/Application Data/FileZilla
- Copy the contents to clipboard
- Go to /home/(user)/.filezilla on Linux
- Paste the contents of the earlier FileZilla installation from Windows. (This will completely replace any new sites/settings/data you've added on Linux, do not do this unless you have nothing on your FileZilla installation that isn't also on the windows installation)
- FileZilla now has all of the settings, sites in site manager, etc which you created on Windows.